# custom Tomcat RPM with native libraries installed (apr) in one package

Tags: apache, tomcat, apr

I created a customer rpm from the latest tomcat just by using a simple unpack.
This tomcat package works both with Ubuntu and RHEL5.5 (64 bit).

I would like to add the native libraries.  What non-tomcat files would I have to include in the extraction to have it support both OS's - I can place these anywhere on the system.

tia